# Class initialization deadlock mechanism explanation

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, initialization, deadlock

I found article(https://habr.com/company/odnoklassniki/blog/255067/) from the @apangin(https://stackoverflow.com/users/3448419/apangin) on my native langugage but I am not able to understand it. Explanation is very concise

Let's consider that code:

```
static class A {
    static final B b = new B();
}

static class B {
    static final A a = new A();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(A::new).start();
    new B();
}
```

You could try to run that code. On my pc it leads to deadlockwith 75% probability/

So we have 2 threads:

Thread_1 is creating instance of A

Thread_2(main thread) is creating instance of B

It is first access to class so it leads(might lead) to concurrent classes A and B initialization.

Next step is not clear for me. Could you explain it?

Comment: what do you mean with "next step"?

Comment: @Alexei, I am about mechanism of deadlock, 2 threads, 2 redources, different acquire order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JVM Specification §5.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.5) describes class initialization procedure in detail. It consists of 12 steps.

At step 6 the class is marked as "in progress of initialization by the current thread".

> 6. Otherwise, record the fact that initialization of the Class object for C is in progress by the current thread, and release LC.

So `Thread_1` starts initializing class `A` and marks it as being initialized by `Thread_1`. Similarly class `B` is marked as being initialized by `Thread_2`.

At step 9 the static initializer is invoked.

> 9. Next, execute the class or interface initialization method of C.

The static initializer of `A` creates an instance of `B`, which is not yet fully initialized, so `Thread_1` (while in progress of initializing `A`) recursively starts the procedure of initializing `B`.

At step 2 of the procedure it detects that class `B` is in progress of initialization by different thread and blocks.

> 2. If the Class object for C indicates that initialization is in progress for C by some other thread, then release LC and block the current thread until informed that the in-progress initialization has completed, at which time repeat this procedure.

Symmetrically `Thread_2` starts initialization of `A`, detects that it is already being initialized by different thread and also blocks at step 2. Both threads are blocked waiting for each other.

Note: the class is marked as fully initialized and notifies other threads *after* successful invocation of static initializer, which never happens in this case.

> 10. If the execution of the class or interface initialization method completes normally, then acquire LC, label the Class object for C as fully initialized, notify all waiting threads, release LC, and complete this procedure normally.

Comment: In your article you mentoioned about bug like that? https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1237 How was it fixed? Which alternatives can we use to fix such bugs?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Yes, exactly this bug. The issue on github has a link to [the fix](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/pull/1239/files).

Comment: So **OperatorImpl** static initialization block was just removed)

Answer (score 2):

> Thread_1 is creating instance of A

Yes. And the `new` keyword requires the class `A` to be initialized.

> Thread_2(main thread) is creating instance of B

Yes. And the `new` keyword also requires the class `B` to be initialized.

But there is a dependency between these classes in the `clinit` (`static` blocks and `static` fields initialization).

---

From [JLS. 12.4.2. Detailed Initialization Procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2):

> For each class or interface C, there is a **unique initialization lock** LC. The mapping from C to LC is left to the discretion of the Java Virtual Machine implementation. The procedure for initializing C is then as follows:
>
> 1. **Synchronize on the initialization lock**, LC, for C. This involves **waiting until the current thread can acquire LC**.

(Other steps are omitted, but the first is the most important one)

So here's what might happen:

`Thread_1`:

1. Sees that it should create an instance of `A` class (`new`)
2. Begins class `A` initialization (first `A` class usage)
3. Acquires initialization lock of the `A` class.

(Here the OS thread scheduler decides that it's time to suspend the `Thread_1` and give some time to `main` thread)

And the `main` thread:

1. Sees that it should create an instance of `B` class (`new`)
2. Begins class `B` initialization (first `B` class usage)
3. Acquires initialization lock of the `B` class.

The os thread scheduler now suspends thread `main` and gives some time to `Thread_1`.

The `Thread_1` continues:

4. It sees `static final B b = new B();`
5. It is not allowed to create a new instance of `B`, because the `B` class is not initialized yet.
6. It tries to acquire initialization lock of the `B` class, but the lock is held by the `main` thread.

Thread scheduler again suspends `Thread_1` and gives some time to `main`. And it continues:

4. It sees `static final A a = new A();`
5. It is not allowed to create a new instance of `A`, because the `B` class is not initialized yet.
6. It tries to acquire initialization lock of the `A` class, but the lock is held by `Thread_1` thread.

So here is a deadlock:

1. The `Thread_1` holds `A` initialization lock and wants to acquire the `B` class initialization lock
2. The `main` thread holds `B` initialization lock and wants to acquire the `A` class initialization lock