# All of the threads are blocked in RUNABLE state for 10 hours

Tags: multithreading, glassfish, eclipselink, block

As the following dump, some nodes happen by chance that the thread raises with the time and finally all of the threads are in this status for more than 10 hours and the system are hanging.
We are using the EclipseLink OXM 2.6.4, is there a known bug for EclipseLink OXM? or do anybody encountered a similar problem?

```
#695 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f3c00875000 nid=0x48f in Object.wait() [0x00007f3b4c709000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl.getValue(JsonParserImpl.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl.getObject(JsonParserImpl.java:339)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl.getObject(JsonParserImpl.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.read(JsonReaderImpl.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JsonStructureReader.parse(JsonStructureReader.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:1016)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLUnmarshaller.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:349)
```

Comment: Maybe a full thread dump might be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure they are 'stuck'? repeated thread dumps might show some progress, and it could just be it is extremely slow going, or goes in/out of similar stack processing because of a complex object model. That or your JVM has a bug, as there is nothing in that getValue method that is locking, so it shouldn't be there for an extended period of time.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your reply, and yes, I am sure it stuck, because after 10 hours later without any new request, these runnable threads are still there. And yes I have checked source code of glassfish, I can not find the reasonable explanation of this.. maybe caused by input stream stuck?

Comment: another information, there is a server restart before the problem

Comment: I would check for JVM issues then, as nothing on that line indicates a potential problem or something to lock on. You will have to profile other data from the JVM, memory and such, to see if something is out of the ordinary that is causing it.

Comment: JsonStringImpl implements JsonString, JsonString inherits JsonValue，
and there is a static attribute "static JsonValue NULL = new JsonValueImpl(JsonValue.ValueType.NULL);
"  in JsonValue.class, and JsonValueImpl implement JsonValue.class, It looks very strange, so it won't loop deadlock? why should it writed this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53682182/class-initialization-deadlock-mechanism-explanation

Comment: javax.json-api-1.1.jar
javax.json-1.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

```
0x00007f47a017f705  __pthread_cond_wait + 0xc5
0x00007f479f2baaf5  _ZN13ObjectMonitor4waitElbP6Thread + 0xa65
0x00007f479efeec40  _ZN13InstanceKlass15initialize_implE19instanceKlassHandleP6Thread + 0x2f0
0x00007f479efeeec1  _ZN13InstanceKlass10initializeEP6Thread + 0x41
0x00007f479f02edfa  _ZN18InterpreterRuntime4_newEP10JavaThreadP12ConstantPooli + 0x23a
0x00007f4761024d8f  * org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl.getValue() bci:96 line:185 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007f4761008020  * org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl.getObject(javax.json.JsonObjectBuilder) bci:39 line:339 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007f4761008020  * org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl.getObject() bci:37 line:173 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007f4761008020  * org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.read() bci:67 line:94 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007f47610080f1  * org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JsonStructureReader.parse(org.xml.sax.InputSource) bci:127 line:139 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007f4761008294  * org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(org.xml.sax.XMLReader, org.xml.sax.InputSource, java.lang.Class) bci:335 line:1016 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007f4761008020  * org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(org.xml.sax.InputSource, java.lang.Class) bci:71 line:452 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007f4761008020  * org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(java.io.InputStream, java.lang.Class) bci:48 line:400 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007f4761008020  * org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(javax.xml.transform.Source, java.lang.Class) bci:156 line:741 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007f47610080f1  * org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.unmarshal(javax.xml.transform.Source, java.lang.Class) bci:159 line:649 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007f4761008020  * org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(javax.xml.transform.Source, java.lang.Class) bci:25 line:349 (Interpreted frame)
```

Comment: The problem will happen by chance after the restart, I think it may relate to the loading order of the jar.